# Perfmon - # logical threads explodes

Tags: c#, multithreading, perfmon

I experience that a single, particular w3wp process jumps up to an astonishing +400.000.000.000 logic threads according to perfmon.

I have added screenshots of perfmon in "zoomed in" and "zoomed out" mode. It looks like the jumps happens at the same time that the physical thread count of the same process falls.

The actual value of the logic thread count is 4,294,967,294  - 1 less than the highest possible uint-value, which leads me to that it could be the value -1 overflowed.

[image: Zoomed in]
[image: Zoomed out]

Does anyone know if this is actually a bug as mentioned in this referenced stackoverflow post? [Incredible number of logical threads; windbg can't see them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048795/incredible-number-of-logical-threads-windbg-cant-see-them)

Or does anyone have any other explanation or debugging suggestions?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sure, you can safely assume you are looking at nonsense data.  And yes, -1.  A threading race bug in the underlying code could get the count off by 1.  But unlikely since it is not an incremental counter and doesn't get close to 0, somewhat more likely is inadequate error checking.  Might be inspiration to reboot the machine.  And to move on, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @ mjwills I totally agree. But this is what I have for now, sorry :)

Comment: @HansPassant perfmon failing again, I guess... This tool is so horrible :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concluded that this was a threading race bug based on the value and the answer from Hans Passant.